# Data driven icon rotation using Mapbox GL

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, icon, rotate

I am trying to rotate map icons based on an "orientation" attribute field (which provides the bearing in degrees). I've tested this in Mapbox studio and it is working fine. When I copy/paste the code from the studio window into my html/js project however, there is no rotation and I can't work out why.

My code looks like below.

```
  map.addSource('points', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://tileset'
    });

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'lights',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': 'points',
    'source-layer': 'layername',
    'layout': {
      'visibility': 'visible',
      'icon-size': 1,
      'icon-image': 'beer-15',
      'icon-rotate': [
        "interpolate",
        ["linear"],
        ["get", "orientation"],
        0, 0,
        350, 350
      ],
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still not an expert, but your interpolate inside of the "icon-rotate" might be the problem. I am not positive. I can show you how I did mine, which works great using an external JSON. Hopefully it will work for you as well (or you can edit my code to work for you) :

In my JS code, it is :

```
map.addLayer({
        id: "direction_layer",
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'direction',
        layout: {
            'icon-image': ['get', 'icon'],
            'icon-rotate': ['get', 'rotation']
        }
    })
```

And my JSON source looks like this :

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-90,34]
     },
     "properties": {
        "description": " ",
        "icon": "direction_icon",
        "rotation": 200
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I agree, the problem must be somewhere in there. If I just set the rotation to a random angle it works fine. Not sure why Mapbox Studio shows the interpolate script for this. I like your more simple approach, but when I replace the interpolate with just ['get', 'orientation'] it still does not rotate. Makes me think it is not collecting the attributes correctly. But then again I can get it to work in Studio with the same file...

Comment: Update: I got it to work now using your expression. The problem was that I had linked the wrong file. One where the 'orientation' field was a string instead of a number, and when I updated the file, I forgot to update it in the code. I suspect the Studio code works as well, but I like your approach better as it is clean and simple. Thanks for leading me onto the issue!

Comment: No problem. I have found that Mapbox examples (and even here on SE) are often too complex. If they kept it simple, things like this would be much easier to understand.